# He did something regularly to see if I needed anything. An event of need actually occured?

Tags: conditional-constructions, present-continuous

> He checked on me regularly during my stay to see if I needed anything.

I've been confused of `if I needed anything`.

Actually needing something has occured in the first place?

Which article can make me understood of this phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two sentences describe the same action:

When he came in he asked, "Do you need anything?"
When he came in he asked if I needed anything.

The word [see](https://www.lexico.com/definition/see) in "**to see if I needed anything**" means:

*Be or become aware of something from observation or from a written or other visual source.*

So perhaps he *asked*, or perhaps he just *looked.* (And if he *saw* I had fallen out of bed...)

Answer (score 0):

At any given time, you may need something.

Each time he checked, there was a possibility of you needing something.

For example, maybe he checked at 8 p.m. and you didn't need anything. But at 9 p.m. you wanted to take a shower. He checked and you told him that you needed a clean towel.

Needs change as intentions and situations change.